# Create custom event class that extends CustomEvent

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, dom-events, extend

I'm trying to create my own class event with predefined options:

```
class TimeoutEvent extends CustomEvent {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);

        this.bubbles = true;
        this.cancelable = true;

        this.type = 'timeout';
    }
}

new TimeoutEvent();
```

but I get an exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'CustomEvent': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

I compiled it with babel 5.8.23 (babel-core 5.8.25).

In the compiled file exception throws on line like so:

```
 CustomEvent.apply(this, arguments);
```

I know that true way is use `document.createEvent('Event');` or new `CustomEvent()`,
but is this the way to extend the default DOM Event class?

Comment: Babel does not support subclassing builtins.